# MongoDB: Sort both parent and child items with similar structure by date

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I have a collection with posts. Each post have some info about post itself as well as array of comments. Posts and Comments have similar structure. My question is: how can i get info about both posts and comments to the same level and sort them by date? Or any order really - all I need is to get flat list of posts and comments sorted by date. Thanks!

```
{
"comments": {
    "0": {
        "date": ISODate("2013-12-24T05:49:27.376Z"),
        "info": {
            "message"▼: "mlknlkjnjlnlkj",
            "date": ISODate("2013-12-24T05:49:27.376Z")
        },
        "type": "comment"
    },
    "1": {
        "date": ISODate("2013-12-25T08:32:47.859Z"),
        "info": {
            "message": "asdddd",
            "date": ISODate("2013-12-25T08:32:47.858Z")
        },
        "type": "comment"
    }
},
"date": ISODate("2013-12-24T04:57:13.741Z"),
"info": {
    "message": "12312312312",
    "date": ISODate("2013-12-24T04:57:13.0Z")
},
"type": "post"
```

}

EDIT: it turns out rockmongo was returning comments in this map looking manner. But in fact comments are in the array rather than map.

Comment: Since you didn't use an array for comment storage, a flatten operation would need to be done manually in your app code. If you had used an array, the aggregation framework may have met your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using mapReduce.

```
map = function () {
    emit(this._id, {
        type: this.type,
        date: this.date,
        info: this.info
    });
    for (var i in this.comments) {
        emit(this.comments[i]._id, {
            type: this.comments[i].type,
            date: this.comments[i].date,
            info: this.comments[i].info
        });
    }
}
```

db.your_collection.mapReduce(map, function () {}, {out: "posts_and_comments"})
db.posts_and_comments.find().sort({"value.date": -1}).pretty()